# How to override the getView method in ArrayAdaptor with dynamically added TextView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

How to `override` the `getView` method  in `ArrayAdaptor` with dynamically added TextView?

Here is what I have so far:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.numbergenerationitemlayout,
                    parent, false);
            holder.FL = (FlowLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.itemFlowLayout);
            holder.FL.setTag(list.get(position));
            view.setTag(holder);

            GameSet GS = (GameSet) list.get(position);
            ArrayList<Element> normal = GS.getNormalNum();
            if (normal != null) {
                for (int x = 0; x < normal.size(); x++) {
                    BallTextView BT = new BallTextView(context, "BLUE_BALL");
                    String text = "" + normal.get(x).getElement();
                    BT.setText(text);
                    holder.FL.addView(BT);
                }
            }

            ArrayList<Element> special = GS.getSpecialNum();
            if (special != null) {
                for (int x = 0; x < special.size(); x++) {
                    BallTextView BT = new BallTextView(context, "ORANGE_BALL");
                    String text = "" + special.get(x).getElement();
                    BT.setText(text);
                    holder.FL.addView(BT);
                }
            }
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            // ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).FL.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder currentHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        currentHolder.position = position;


        return view;
    }
```

The problem I am facing now is that when I add a new data to the array and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`; on the `arrayAdaptor`, the new item is not getting added.

Comment: New data to WHAT array?

Comment: public GameSetArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<GameSet> list) this is the constructor for the adapter. I add the new data to the list that is pass in from the constructor.

Comment: You should call add on the adapter directly and you won't have to manually call notifyDatasetChanged

Comment: That could be an option, but is it efficient to do that why your data is huge?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do

```
  GameSet GS = (GameSet) list.get(position);
```

outside of

```
  if (convertView == null) {}
```

eg right at the start of the `getView()` method because after using the list for a while `convertView` will probably not be `null` anymore.

Comment: If that is true, that means the code under that needs to be outside too. (where I add the textview)

Comment: @Ascorbin is right, the convertView is a view reused so your condition should only contains the inflate and the setTag. You should also be aware that if you use the convertView, it will already contains many BallTextView that you can either reuse or clean.

Comment: The point is if I add new data to the list,  new BallTextView would also need to be added.

Answer (score 0):

The getView method need to be changed, here is the solution:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.numbergenerationitemlayout,
                    parent, false);
            holder.FL = (FlowLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.itemFlowLayout);
            holder.FL.setTag(list.get(position));
            view.setTag(holder);

            GameSet GS = (GameSet) list.get(position);
            ArrayList<Element> normal = GS.getNormalNum();
            if (normal != null) {
                for (int x = 0; x < normal.size(); x++) {
                    BallTextView BT = new BallTextView(context, "BLUE_BALL");
                    holder.FL.addView(BT);
                  //here only add the view that holds the content.
                }
            }

            ArrayList<Element> special = GS.getSpecialNum();
            if (special != null) {
                for (int x = 0; x < special.size(); x++) {
                    BallTextView BT = new BallTextView(context, "ORANGE_BALL");
                   //here only add the view that holds the content.
                    holder.FL.addView(BT);
                }
            }
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            // ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).FL.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder currentHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        currentHolder.position = position;


       //Now do the set text part over here.

        return view;
    }
```

Basically only add the view content holder under the if(convertView ==null) and then do the setText data part outside the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (hasMore) {
        return (int) (Math.ceil((mData.length / 4.0))) + 1;
    } else {
        return (int) (Math.ceil((mData.length / 4.0)));
    }
}

 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (position == getCount() - 1 && hasMore) {
        convertView = new LinearLayout(context);
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
        progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.progress_view_grey_anim));
        ((LinearLayout) convertView).addView(progressBar);

    } else {
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

here is what i usually add a progress view.